# Access file share with python - MFA enabled

Tags: python-3.x, sharepoint, power-automate

I am developing an application in Power Automate which reads from a file share, preferably SharePoint. The files in SharePoint needs to be uploaded from a python script. However, there is Multi Factor Authentication (MFA) enabled on the SharePoint access which is preventing the python script to access the SharePoint.

This is an organization wide setting and I cannot do anything about it. So, I am looking for options to overcome this challenge.

My options are flexible. Task is to read from a file share. Any suggestions regarding this are welcome...